# Tensor product and contraction keeping track of indexes order

Tags: tensors

I have two tensors $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ and $M_{\mu\nu\rho}$ which are defined as following

```
η = DiagonalMatrix[{-1,1,1,1}]
M = Array[Subscript[mSymb, ##] &, {4, 4,4}]
```

I want to consider the tensor product and then contract the indexes in pairs. I want to get the following object

$$
\overline{M}_{\sigma\,\,\,\,\,\alpha}^{\,\,\,\,\mu} = \sum_\nu \eta^{\mu\nu} M_{\sigma \nu\alpha}
$$

I tried with the following function

```
TensorContract[TensorProduct[η,M],{2,4}]
```

But this function instead returns the following object

$$
\tilde{M}^{\mu}_{\,\,\sigma\alpha} = \sum_\nu \eta^{\mu\nu} M_{\sigma \nu\alpha}
$$

You see that the RHS is the same in both cases but the order of the indexes is important when calling the element `M[[σ, μ, α]]`. For example, If `M` was a square matrix, $\tilde{M}$ would be the transpose of the object that I call $\overline{M}$.

How can I tell Mathematica to keep track of the order??

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematica *is* keeping track of the order, you just gave it a different order than you intended.  `TensorProduct[eta,m]` will put the the two slots of `eta` first, then the three slots `m`.  If you want to think of the `\[Sigma]` index as coming first, you need to move it there.  Then the two `\[Nu]` indices will be slots 3 and 4, and you have

```
TensorContract[
   TensorTranspose[
       TensorProduct[eta, M],
       Cycles[{{1, 3}}]
   ], 
   {3, 4}
]
```

Altenatively, you could fix up your first attempt after the fact, again using `TensorTranspose`:

```
TensorTranspose[TensorContract[TensorProduct[eta, M], {2, 4}], Cycles[{{1, 2}}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can create a function to do this:

```
raise[m_, slot_, η_] := TensorContract[
    TensorTranspose[
        TensorProduct[η,m],
        RotateRight[Range[slot+1],2]
    ],
    {{slot+1,slot+2}}
]
```

For your example:

```
η = DiagonalMatrix[{-1,1,1,1}];
M = Array[Subscript[mySymb,##]&,{4,4,4}];

raise[M, 2, eta] //MatrixForm //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{1,1,1} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{1,1,2} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{1,1,3} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{1,1,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,2,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,2,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,2,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,2,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,3,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,3,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,3,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,3,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,4,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,4,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,4,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{1,4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{2,1,1} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{2,1,2} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{2,1,3} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{2,1,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,2,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,2,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,2,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,2,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,3,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,3,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,3,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,3,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,4,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,4,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,4,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{2,4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{3,1,1} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{3,1,2} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{3,1,3} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{3,1,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,2,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,2,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,2,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,2,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,3,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,3,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,3,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,3,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,4,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,4,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,4,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{3,4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{4,1,1} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{4,1,2} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{4,1,3} \\
>  -\operatorname{mySymb}_{4,1,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,2,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,2,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,2,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,2,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,3,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,3,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,3,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,3,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,4,1} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,4,2} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,4,3} \\
>  \operatorname{mySymb}_{4,4,4} \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$